# Jqgrid sort column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to dynamically sort one column of a jqGrid when clicking a button instead of clicking in the column name?

Comment: why not ?? there must be a tweak for that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the button click event set the sort column in the grids postdata and then call a reload on the grid

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    $('#yourgrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {sortname: 'yourColumn', sortorder: 'asc'}).trigger('reloadGrid', [{page: 1}]);
});
```

Comment: The value of `sidx` parameter will be constructed from `sortname` option of jqGrid and the value of `sord` from `sortorder`. So you should do the following: `$('#yourgrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {sortname: 'yourColumn', sortorder: 'asc'}).trigger('reloadGrid', [{page: 1}]);`. Moreover you should close the quote in `$('#mybutton)`.

Answer (score 8):

The fourth time even luckier!.
Using ***true*** in the third parameter will reload the grid for sure.

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('sortGrid', 'id', true, 'asc');
```

If you don't use ***true*** in the third parameter, in the first execution, the order ('asc' or 'desc') is not updated correctly.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution - but not pretty:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {sortname: 'id', sortorder: 'asc'}).trigger('reloadGrid', [{page: 1}]);
$('#gbox_grid .s-ico').css('display','none');
$('#gbox_grid #jqgh_grid_id .s-ico').css('display','');
$('#gbox_grid #jqgh_grid_id .s-ico .ui-icon-triangle-1-s').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

as shown here

http://jsfiddle.net/qhYLT/

---

Another way to sort by a column programatically - specifying the order:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {sortorder: 'desc'});
$('#grid').jqGrid('sortGrid', 'id');
```

The sortGrid fires off a reload for you.  It wouldn't be complete without a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/uTqD5/

---

Third time lucky!  An undocumented feature:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('sortGrid', 'id', '', 'asc');
```